# Is it possible to use SQLite on a VPS for a Discord bot?

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

Is it possible to use SQLite on a VPS as a database? I've been making a Discord bot and I used SQLite for leveling, warns and changing prefix etc.

I don't really want to use JSON as a database since I'll be making this bot a public bot for everyone's usage, and JSON seems to slow down when the file gets chunky enough. Also using SQLite seemed easier for me rather than using JSON.

If SQLite doesn't work on a VPS, is there an alternative way of making a database for leveling or other type of stuff that requires a database?

Answer (score 2):

The sqlite3 module is part of the standard Python library, so any standard Ubuntu installation or any VPS with Python installed will not require further installation.

If you need to manually install it use:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```

Keep in mind that Sqlite can only support one writer at a time. The official documentation talks about the pros and cons of SQLite (https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html)